# Bitbucket Pipelines echo environment variable

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to extract the JIRA issue within a feature branch name, for instance: `feature/SLUG-1234-feature-name`. What's wrong with this:

`- declare -x NEW_APP_NAME=slug-$(echo '"$BITBUCKET_BRANCH"' | grep "(SLUG-\d+)" -E -o | grep "(\d+)" -E -o)`

or this:

`- declare -x NEW_APP_NAME=slug-$(echo $BITBUCKET_BRANCH | grep "(SLUG-\d+)" -E -o | grep "(\d+)" -E -o)`

or this:

`- NEW_APP_NAME=slug-$(echo '"$BITBUCKET_BRANCH"' | grep "(SLUG-\d+)" -E -o | grep "(\d+)" -E -o)`

None are working and I'm not even getting a failure error!

Answer (score 1):

That may sound odd, but I found that when using more complex commands, similar to your ones, you have to wrap them in single quotes (plus, in your case, tweak the quoting inside), to make Bb Pipelines process them correctly.

Comment: Thank you. “Tweak the quoting inside”... what do you mean? Around the variable?

Comment: You have single quotes in the statement, and wrapping the whole statement in single quotes would obviously create invalid syntax. But having said that: I’d say you don’t need the inner single quotes, so probably you can just drop them and wrap everything in single quotes.